# Can we Query multi-level lookup columns in SharePoint Online Using Rest API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

There are 3 SharePoint Lists which have these columns:

**PersonList :**

1. Title
2. AddressLookupColumn

**AddressList :**

1. Title
2. AddressTypeLookupColumn

**AddressTypeList :**

1. Title

What I need is the Name of Person, Address, and Address Type using the oData REST API.

Below is my query:

```
https://mysitecollection/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('PersonList')/items?$select=Title,AddressLookupColumn/Title,AddressLookupColumn/AddressTypeLookupColumn/Title&$Expand=AddressLookupColumn,AddressLookupColumn/AddressTypeLookupColumn_
```

It gives me this error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The query to field 'AddressLookupColumn/AddressTypeLookupColumn' is not valid.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

How can I correct my query?

Comment: My guess is that you won't be able to do a two-level-deep lookup in a single query. You might need to do a second query against the AddressList using the `AddressLookupColumn/ID` value from the PersonList.

Answer (score 0):

Nested query is not supported in SharePoint Rest call

Two level `$expand` or nested query is not supported in SharePoint REST API. For example, you are querying on A list and A has a lookup column from B list. B has a lookup column from C list. Hence, if you are querying on A list, you can only `$expand` all the columns of B.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('A')?$select={columns for B}&$expand=B
```

You cannot `$expand` any column from C. The reason is there is no direct relation between A and C.

**Workaround #1:**

At first, get the item Ids of B list, make another REST call to B list and `$expand` the columns of C.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('B')/items({ItemId})?$select={select column from c}&$expand=C
```

You can use `$batch` request to get the multiple items at a time but $batch request has no support in SharePoint 2013.

For more information:
[SharePoint REST API Limitation](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-limitation).